# String Reverse Not Happeing

Tags: c++, string

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string A="India";
    string B;
    int n=A.length();
    
   for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      B[n-i-1] = A[i];  
   }
   
   
       cout<<B[i];
   
return 0;
}
```

I just could found why string is not reversing. It is showing blank output

Is there a error in the way of printing String B.

Comment: `B` never had a chance to allocate the space for what you want to change. Using `B.resize(A.size());` should help. Note that `std::string` doesn't allocate the memory while you access the index that is out of bound.

Comment: Just assign `A` to `B` and then use `std::reverse()` on `B`, no need for a manual loop.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that you have done wrong is you forgot to allocate size of
`String B`. All you need to done is to pre allocate the memory of `String B`. So in nutshell your code should be like this,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string A="India";
    string B;
    int n=A.length();
    B.resize(n);    //allocating the memory for B
   for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      B[n-i-1] = A[i];  
   }
   
   
       cout<<B[i];
   
return 0;
}
```